# Construct a discrete subset such that every point of $\partial D$ is a limit point of discrete subset

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, discrete-geometry, domain-theory

1. $D$ is a domain in $\Bbb C$, please construct a discrete subset $E$ of $D$ such that every point of $\partial D\subset \Bbb C$ is a limit point of $E$
2. $D$ is a unbound domain in $\Bbb C$, please construct a discrete subset $E$ of $D$ such that every point of $\partial D$( $\infty \in \partial D$ is seen as subset of the extended plane) is a limit point of $E$

   Definition:  $E$ is  a discrete subset of $D$ if $E$ has no limit point that belongs to $D$

---

the problem is related to [The Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem)

Well, if $D=\Bbb C$, let $ E$ be the positive integers. $\partial \Bbb C=\{\infty\}$

For example , What about $D$ if $D$ is  the unit disk $\{z:|z|<1\}$ ?

Comment: The set of positive integers has no limit points in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: I think, you are supposed to do this for arbitrary domain in ${\mathbb C}$. But for $D={\mathbb C}$ your solution is correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott   $\partial \Bbb C=\{\infty\}$

Comment: @MoisheKohan   Yes   thank you

Comment: @ziangchen: The fact remains that the set of positive integers has no limit points in $\Bbb C$: there is no point $\infty$ in $\Bbb C$. Possibly you are working in some context in which $\Bbb C$ has been extended to its one-point compactification, but then it is no longer $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott   thank you very much! I edit the problem

Comment: @ziangchen: You’re welcome! For an actual example of the sort of thing that I suspect is wanted for the first part, let $$D=\{x+iy\in\Bbb C:y>0\}\;.$$ For $n\in\Bbb N$ let 
$$E_n=\left\{\frac{k+i}{2^n}:k\in\Bbb Z\right\}\;,$$ and let $E=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}E_n$. Then $E$ is a discrete subset of $D$ whose set of limit points is the real axis, which is also the boundary of $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this note](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/26.pdf) you'll find a proof that in a metric space, the boundary of any open set is the set of limit points of a discrete subset, which is what you need.